# Difficulties sending a notification with Firebase cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a cloud function which is going so send a notification to all the users of an iOS app. As a first test I want to send a notification to only one user.

Below is the relevant code. When I run it this is what appears in the browser:

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

Can someone see where I am doing it wrong?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: 'myAppID',
    clientEmail: 'firebase-adminsdk-gotiq@edo-press-japan.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    privateKey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n........=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
  }),
  databaseURL: 'https://myApp.firebaseio.com'
});

let registrationToken = "112233..aabbcc...7788";
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var payload = {
        data:{
          title: "ELR",
          body: "The world has been messed up."
        },
        token: registrationToken
    };

    admin.messaging().send(payload)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
        response.send("Hello from Firebase! - ALL IS GOOD !!");
        //return true;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
        response.send("Hello from Firebase! - FAILED !!");
        //return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: Check the Cloud Functions logs in the web console.

Comment: I did try that, but did not see anything. I may have some wrong settings preventing me from accessing the debug information.

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in variable names in your code: on one hand you use `res` and on the other hand you use `response`. You should modify it as follows:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var payload = {
        data:{
          title: "ELR",
          body: "The world has been messed up."
        },
        token: registrationToken
    };

    admin.messaging().send(payload)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
        res.send("Hello from Firebase! - ALL IS GOOD !!");  // <-- here use res and not response
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
        res.status(500).send("Hello from Firebase! - FAILED !!"); // <-- here, use res and add status(500)
    })
})
```

Also, note that I have changed the last line to `res.status(500).send()`, as advised in the official video series from Doug, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA

[image]

Comment: I changed the code as you say. I get : "Hello from Firebase! - FAILED !!" I guess it's alreay better than "Error: could not handle the request". But what I want is a SUCCESS, as you guess.

Comment: What do you see in the Cloud Functions log on the Firebase console?

Comment: I just added a screenshot at the end of your answer.

Comment: I can see: Error: The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token.
How do I get a valid FCM registration token?

Comment: Yes you are getting an error that "the registration token is not a valid fcm registration token". You should either re-issue a token or search some similar cases https://www.google.com/search?q=the+registration+token+is+not+a+valid+fcm+registration+token+FirebaseMessagingError

Comment: In JavaScript: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message#access_the_registration_token